# "INVALID_FIELD: LastViewedDate" when saving recordEditForm

Tags: lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I have the following recordEditForm component which does *not* use `LastViewedDate`:

```
<aura:component description="ErrorTesting" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="TestChild__c">
    <lightning:messages/>
    <lightning:inputField label="TestMaster" fieldName = "TestMaster__c"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

However, when the component is saved, the following error message appears:

> INVALID_FIELD: LastViewedDate != null ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:90 No such column 'LastViewedDate' on entity 'TestMaster__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

[image]

Any insight as to why I would get this error even though I'm not referencing this field would be helpful. It may be useful to note that "TestMaster__c" is a master-detail field.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to this issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC

Comment: Can you make sure there's no errant spaces between `fieldName = "TestMaster__c"`? It's in your post so did your component compile with those spaces too?

Answer (score 3):

I've added Tab for the Custom Object and in that case LastViewedDate appeared on the object. It seems that Salesforce restricts access to LastViewedDate if there is no Tab on the object

Comment: Were you able to handle this without Custom tab ?
describe is giving back  LastViewedDate in our manage package when there is no tab.

Comment: No I wasnt' able to fix it without custom tab. Probably you can try create tab after package is installed with jsforce. so it not shown to business users